# Trying to get the random.choice ouput to work with if statement. This is the code:

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

animal = ["bird", "mammal", "fish", "insect", "reptile"]
#select weighted sample from list and put it into variable
rand_animal = (random.choices(animal, weights=(50, 20, 10, 10, 10), k=1))
print(rand_animal)
time.sleep(1)

#prints output based on the weighted selection
if rand_animal == "bird":
   print("CHIRP CHRIP")
else:
   print("Not a bird")
```

The problem when I run it, is that the `else` statement always prints `Not a bird`. Is there a way to call the random.choices k sample into another variable? Is that output not fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read code carefully and [look for problems yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before posting. (Hint: `choice` and `choices` are not the same thing. Hint: Instead of checking whether `rand_animal` is a specific thing, for debugging purposes, find out **what it is**. Does that make sense? (Sub-hint: what would you expect `random.choices` to do when `k` *isn't* `1`?))

Comment: "Is there a way to call the random.choices k sample into another variable?" I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, You are trying to compare list and string.

By adding `[0]` position you will compare the first value of `rand_animal` with string.

Code:

```
#prints output based on the weighted selection
if rand_animal[0] == "bird":
    print("CHIRP CHRIP")
else:
    print("Not a bird")
```

Output:

```
['bird']
CHIRP CHRIP
```